# How to update same table in parallel using threads in DB2?

Tags: multithreading, sql-update, db2

I am trying to update a single table in parallel (3 update statements with different where clause) using 3 threads. But when I am trying to examine the behavior of running the code, it appears the update is happening serially.

So my question, can we update the same table in parallel or it will always happen serially even using threads?

Please advice.

Comment: 1) It depends on what transaction level you're using. 2) It depends on if the `WHERE` clauses overlap (if they **don't** run in serial, you can have problems). 3) It depends on your hardware (the DB may not parallelize something if it can only use 1 core, or some other factor). 4) It depends on how you submit the queries.  5) It depends on how much work it has to do... could you post your queries, and how you're calling them?

Comment: platform and version may also play a part..

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: I am using ksh test shell script on aix box to run another ksh script in parallel. In my first script I am calling second script as....for i in "${SUBARRAY[@]}";do (sh /home/achhatw/Test/accums_outbound.sh $i &) ;done. So the second script(accums_outbound.sh) will be executed as 4 different process simultaneously, as there are 4 elements in array. So now in second script(accums_outbound.sh) I am executing multiple db select statements and an update statement. So update is affecting around 100 thousand records.

Comment: Update query : UPDATE $BAT_SCHEMA.T_STORE t set t.T_STS_CD = 'C' , t.T_PRCSSD_DTTM = '${current_date_yyyymmddhhmmss}' where t.T_PRTNR_ID = '${sub}' and t.TRANS_STS_CD = 'N' and t.TRANS_RECV_DTTM < '${todate}:00:00'

Comment: 1) please put that kind of info in your question. 2) We also need to see your second script, and any additional settings for the tool (to determine things like transaction settings).  However, your biggest problem appears to be application design, as your current statement implies a _requirement_ for serial access. It might also be important to know what indices you have.  Your date range query probably isn't helping any either - can you restrict it more?